# In C, is there a difference between a NULL pointer and a pointer that points to 0? If so, what?

Tags: c, pointers, null, zero

In C, what is the difference between a NULL pointer and a pointer that points to 0?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ISO/IEC 9899:TC2 states in `6.3.2.3 Pointers`

> 3  An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression
>   cast to type void *, is called a null pointer constant.55) If a null
>   pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting
>   pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a
>   pointer to any object or function

The macro NULL expands to an *implementation-defined* null pointer constant.

Any two null pointers shall compare equal.

Answer (score 6):

Yes there is. The standard dictates that `NULL` always points to invalid memory. But it does not state that the integer representation of the pointer must be 0. I've never come across an implementation for which `NULL` was other than 0, but that is not mandated by the standard.

Note that assigning the literal `0` to a pointer does not mean that the pointer assumes the integer representation of 0. It means that the special null pointer value is assigned to the pointer variable.

Comment: Also note that `int *ptr = 0;` always results in a null pointer thanks to a special rule, because `0` is a so-called "null pointer constant". This holds even if you're on some peculiar implementation where a null pointer is different from address 0. However, `int i = 0; int *ptr = (int*)i;` does not necessarily result in a null pointer. So you won't normally encounter "a pointer that points to the 0 address" except in a context where it is a null pointer, but the standard permits it.

Comment: @David, in your second para you mean "doesn't", don't you? And `NULL` is always a `0` value by definition of the standard, which might be a valid address, e.g in the kernel. So one should better distinguish `NULL` more clearly from the internal representation of a null pointer, which, as you say could be something different.

Comment: Also note that it's implementation-defined whether `int *ptr = (int *)(0,0);` yields a null pointer (since `(0,0)` is not specified to be an integer constant expression, but may be an additional implementation-defined integer constant expression).

Comment: Or may not be an implementation-defined ICE at all, but nevertheless be implementation-defined to yield a null pointer when cast to pointer type. Besides, `(0,0)` isn't really code, it's a little owl.

Comment: @Jens: In C, `NULL` is not necessarily a 0 value, it could be `(void*)0`, which *is* a null pointer value. If a null pointer refers to a valid object in the kernel, then the kernel isn't a conforming C environment (hence that painful bug with `-fdelete-null-pointer-checks`), since the standard guarantees that a null pointer compares unequal to any pointer to an object.

Comment: @Steve, I am well aware of that. I just found David's explanation not clear enough, since it uses the term `NULL` for the internal representation of a null pointer, and these are clearly two different things.

Answer (score 3):

Evaluating the literal `0` in a pointer context is identical to `NULL`. Whatever bit pattern the compiler uses to represent a `NULL` pointer is hidden.

Answer (score 1):

The old comp.lang.c FAQ has a big section on the null pointer and it's worth a read.

[comp.lang.c null pointers](http://c-faq.com/null/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that a `NULL` pointer should somehow represent a memory area that is invalid.
So since in the lower memory segments the OS code is mapped, the value of 0 has been used (to represent the NULL pointer) since this area in memory does not belong to the user's program but is mapped to the OS code.