# Difference between uninitialized and null pointer

Tags: c, pointers, null

Is there any difference between null pointer and uninitialized pointer?
This question was asked in one of the interviews. 
Could you please explain the difference that they have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After accept answer

```
void foo(void) {
  void *uninitialized_pointer;
  void *null_pointer = null_pointer_generator();
  ...
}
```

**`uninitialized_pointer`** in *uninitialized*.  It may have a valid pointer value in it.  It may have a value that compares to `NULL`. It may have not have *any* pointer value in it.  C does not have a defined method to even copy or print its value.

```
 // These are undefined behavior.
 void *another_pointer = uninitialized_pointer;
 unsigned x = uninitialized_pointer*0;
 printf("%p\n",  uninitialized_pointer);
```

Code can assign `uninitialized_pointer`, compute its size or pass its address.

```
 // These are defined behavior.
 uninitialized_pointer = malloc(1);
 uninitialized_pointer = NULL;
 printf("%zu\n", sizeof uninitialized_pointer);
 foo(&uninitialized_pointer);
```

---

The variable **`null_pointer`** has a value that compares equally to the *null pointer constant* (see below) and so in a *null pointer*.  A *null pointer* may be unique bit pattern or there may be many of them in a system.  They *all* compare equally to the *null pointer constant* and to each other.  A *null pointer* may or may not be a valid address in the system although it will not compare equally to any object, variable, member, function in your program.

Attempting to dereference a *null pointer* is undefined behavior: it may cause a seg-fault - it may not.

---

`NULL` is the *null pointer constant*.  When assigned to a pointer, that pointer  is a *null pointer*.  When `0` is assigned to a pointer, that pointer is a *null pointer*.  These may/may not be different *null pointers*.  They will compare equally to each other.

```
  void *null_pointer1 = NULL;
  void *null_pointer2 = 0;
  // The 2 pointer may/may not have the same bit pattern.
  printf("%p\n%p\n", null_pointer1, null_pointer2);

  // They will always compare as equal.
  printf("%d\n", null_pointer1 == null_pointer2);

  // Always compare as unequal.
  int x;
  printf("%d\n", null_pointer1 == &x);
```

Answer (score 7):

Well, the difference is exactly that. Null pointer is initialized to null, and as such has defined meaning. You can check it for null, and dereferencing it will (on all platforms I know) cause a program to crash with meaningful diagnostics. You can also use null pointers in some specific hacks.
Unitinialized pointers, on the other hand, are just random and should be avoided.

Comment: So, you don't know DOS anymore? OR any embedded system? Because those are unlikely to immediately crash on misuse of nullpointers.

Comment: My DOS experience is extremely limited. And I do not have any experience with embedded systems.

Answer (score 4):

Take an uninitialized pointer:

```
int* ptr;//points to any location in memory
```

Take a null pointer:

```
int* ptr = NULL;//normally points to 0x0 (0)
```

Both would cause undefined behaviour if dereferenced. `NULL` is often defined as `0`.

Comment: `NULL` is just a concept. It is represented by `0` in C, but that doesn't necessarily mean that it points to address 0x0. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613175/in-c-is-there-a-difference-between-a-null-pointer-and-a-pointer-that-points-to

Comment: @PCLuddite - I meant due to NULL normally being defined as 0 , the pointer will normally thus point to 0x0

Comment: But that's not true. NULL is defined in the language as 0, but upon compilation, it may point to somewhere else that the hardware defines as NULL.

Comment: @NDeepK - what do you mean?

Comment: The language only guarantees that the nullpointer, whatever address it might be represented by, is distinct from any valid pointer.

Comment: @PCLuddite the only reason for me writing that `int* ptr = NULL` makes a pointer point to 0x0 is that MSVC does that so I guess I should have researched further.

Comment: @Joe I'm sure that `NULL` in MSVC is defined as `0` or `(void*)0`, but it still doesn't mean that when it's compiled that it actually points to `0x0`.

Comment: @PCLuddite - with my debugger (using MSVC), a null pointer's address is 0x0

Comment: Alright! So it means that an uninitialized pointer shows an undefined behavior as one would not know which address will it point to. But, a pointer initialized to null (i.e., a null pointer) will point to 0x0 so that it doesn't show an undefined behavior which could sometimes lead to crash.

Comment: @NDeepK Not exactly. Using an uninitialized pointer is undefined behavior, but dereferencing a NULL pointer is also undefined behavior (both could lead to a crash). The difference is that an uninitialized pointer could be anything, but a NULL pointer has a definite value (i.e. `NULL`).

Comment: `int i = 0; printf("%zu %zu", sizeof i, sizeof NULL); /* => 4 8 */`

Answer (score 3):

An uninitialized pointer stores an undefined value.

A null pointer stores a defined value, but one that is defined by the environment to not be a valid address for any member or object.

Ok... I googled it for you, heres the link: [Null pointer vs uninitialized pointer](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/161910-null-pointer-vs-uninitialized-pointer.html)

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog Sir, even I googled it, but could not understand the meaning of "defined by the environment", as mentioned in the definition of null pointer. 
Does it mean that a variable can't have an address that is 0 (null)?

Comment: For the most part, yes. Unless  you have specifically assigned it NULL.

Comment: @NDeepK It means that the null pointer is guaranteed to be different than any other pointer. The environment defines what it is.

Comment: @NDeepK is right.  It could either be assigned 0 or something else, just depends on what the environment defines the pointer as. Therefore do not ever assume it will be 0 or NULL.

Answer (score 3):

The base difference is that an uninitiated pointer has an indeterminate value whereas a NULL pointer has a *defined* value which is `NULL`.

Regarding the NULL pointer, from `C11`, chapter §6.3.2.3

> An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type `void *`, is called a null pointer constant. If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a *null pointer* is guaranteed to compare unequal
>   to a pointer to any object or function.

FWIW, the macro `NULL` is defined in `<stddef.h>`, as a null pointer constant.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. There is a difference in uninitialized and a null pointer. An uninitialized pointer can point to any (unknown) memory location . A null pointer initialized with `NULL`; implementation-defined null pointer constant.