# In C, how to distinguish an uninitialized pointer from a null pointer?

Tags: c, null

As I've understood from the answers to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32211593/difference-between-uninitialized-and-null-pointer), an uninitialized pointer can contain pretty much anything and could therefore also happen to equal to `NULL`. Is there a way to distinguish uninitialized pointers from null pointers, for example by giving them a specific value?

For example, consider:

```
// could potentially print
FILE *f1;
if (f1 == NULL)
    fprintf(stderr, "f1 is NULL");

// will never print, but is this a good/safe way?
FILE *f2 = -1;
if (f2 == NULL)
    fprintf(stderr, "f2 is NULL");
```

Comment: If you worry about using uninitialized local variables, then *explicitly initialize them*. That's the only safe solution. And for pointers the only safe "not a valid pointer" value is `NULL`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude What if I want to pass an uninitialized ptr to a function BUT have that be optional? Using `NULL` to signal that the argument should not be used is not an option, but if the function is supposed to initialize the ptr for me in any other case? I assume I need an entirely different approach?

Comment: Then you need to come up with another abstraction, wrapping the "optional" values using structures or functions that are designed to handle "uninitialized" data. I put "uninitialized" in quotes because the data can't really *be* uninitialized, the API or structure need to have an initialized flag that tells if the wrapped real data is initialized or not.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: If you want your function to initialize the pointer, `NULL` is fine to mark the absence of a value because in every other case you'd have to pass the address of the pointer: `f(&ptr)` vs. `f(NULL)`. If you didn't pass `&ptr`, `f` could not modify `ptr`.

Comment: @melpomene Ah, of course! I guess one can tell that I'm quite new to C still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

An uninitialised value could be anything. An uninitialised pointer could point anywhere. It could even point to valid data by sheer coincidence.

Initialise your pointers to `NULL` or a real value; if you ever find yourself seeing uninitialised values then a programmer somewhere has done something wrong.

Comment: Ah well, I was afraid so. Thanks for confirming.