# Conflicting point between char array and char pointer with returning the adress

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, char

> **Purpose :** My main purpose was to create a string in some kind of function , it should return an adress , by returning adress using the string in main.
>   But I learned char array and char pointer actually using for the same purpose.

***If we suppose that's true , We have these declaration :***

`char *arr` and `char arr[10]`  , `*(arr+9)=arr[10]` isn't it?

> **Application 1** does **not** work.
>   **Application 2** does **work** fine.

**Application 1:**

```c
#include <stdio.h> 
char *foo(char arr[]);

int main(void)
{

    char example[10];
    example=foo(example);
    printf("%s\n",example);

    return 0;   
}
char *foo(char arr[])
{
    arr[10]="attempt";

    return arr;
}
```

**Application 2:**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
char *foo(char*);
int main(void)
{
    char *example;
    example=foo(example);
    printf("%s\n",example);
    return 0;
}
char *foo(char* arr)
{
    arr="attempt";
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: If you declare `char arr[10];` (10 elements, numbered 0 to 9) then valid indices are `0` to `9`, not `10`. So `*(a + 9)` is valid, but `*(a + 10)` is not.

Comment: Sorry It is true ,  I am going to edit it.

Comment: if you try to compile your first code example with lets say the gcc compiler, you would recieve the following error  > error: assignment to expression with array type  which occurs in line 8 at `example=foo(example);`

Comment: But assigning a string to char (be it arr[0], arr[9] or arr[10] -- they are all elements of the array, and not the array), doesn't make sense. You want to use strcpy() or strncpy() instead, to copy the string to the array: `strncpy(arr, "attempt", 10);`.

Comment: I know that It is possible , but I want to overcome this problem with returning the adress from function.

Comment: I'd expect `arr[10]="attempt";` to at least give a warning?  What is your compiler/options?

Comment: and If you compile (lets say you use gcc) you will also recieve the following warning > warning: assignment to ‘char’ from ‘char *’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]  in line 14 at `arr[10]="attempt\n";`

Comment: Review `char *example;

    example=foo(example);`.  What value is `foo()` given in that function call as `example` is not yet assigned a value.

Comment: This statement `arr[10]="attempt";` in the first instance of `*foo()` function should be an error in anything beyond C99.  (`LLVM` gives _Error: redefinition of 'arr' with a different type: char[10] vs char *._ )

Answer (score 3):

Your code will invoke *[undefined behavior](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/undefined-behavior-c-cpp/)* in both segments.  ( Even though you have observed that *Code `2` works*, it only *seems* to work.  In reality a *[failure is lurking](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)*, and can show without warning. )

Make these corrections to address that problem, and see comments for explanations:

In ***code 1***:

```
//int main(void){
int main(void){//int main(void) is minimum prototype for main function.

    //char example[10];               // this will invoke undefined behavior
    char example[10] = {"something"}; // 'example' initialized with content,
                                      // thus averting undefined behavior
    //example=foo(example);
    strcpy (example, foo(example));  // char array is not assignable using `=`
                                     // use strcpy to transfer result of "foo"
    printf("%s\n",example);

    return 0;   
}
char *foo(char arr[]) //note: char arr[] decays into char *arr
{
    //char arr[10]="attempt"; // Error: redefinition of 'arr' with a 
                              // different type: char[10] vs char *

    arr = "attempt"; //because char [] decays into char *, 'arr' is usable as is.

    return arr;
}
```

To answer your question in comments: *Why using strcpy function* [*after variable* ***example*** *was initialized*] *is not a undefined behaviour*.
First the definition of a C string is important to know.  ( *[C string definition is found here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_strings.htm)*. )
The variable `example` in its original form, i.e. initialized:

```
char example[10];
```

Can contain anything.  For example:

```
|%|h|8|\#|d|o|-|~|*|U|?|?|?|?|
//                   ^end of memory for 'example`
// note that the character in example[9] == 'U', not NULL, therefore, not a C string.
```

This would cause the function `strcpy()` to fail.  Initializing guarantees predictable results:

```
char example[10] = {"something"};//properly initialized
|s|o|m|e|t|h|i|n|g|0|?|?|?|?|
//                  ^end of memory for 'example`
//or
char example[10] = {0};          //also properly initialized
|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|?|?|?|?|
//                  ^end of memory for 'example`
(This would require an extra step to place proper content.):
strcpy(example, "something");
```

The only *required* adjustment to ***Code 2*** is to initialize the pointer before using:  (See the reason why pointer must be initialized *[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32214130/645128)*.)

```
char *foo(char*);

//int main(void){
int main(void){//int main(void) is minimum prototype for main function.
{
    //char *example; // passing this will envoke undefined behavior
    char *example = NULL;// must initialize before using             

    example=foo(example);

    printf("%s\n",example);

    return 0;
}
char *foo(char* arr)
{
    arr="attempt";

    return arr;
}
```

Comment: ı knew that It was going to work with using strcpy function. Why using strcpy function is not a undefined behaviour ?

Comment: @SeptemberSKY - because in this case, the argument `example` has been initialized with content.  Before that, the contents were undefined, meaning that it may not have been a _null terminated char array_, which is the definition of a C string.  Therefore, `strcpy()` may, or may not have worked.

Comment: In the 2nd case, `char *example = NULL;` would be sufficient.  "must initialize before using, and with a value that ... ensures enough space" is unclear here.

Answer (score 1):

Both do not "work" for different reasons.

The first is *undefined behavior* (UB) as code attempts to assign an element outside the bounds of `example[10]`.

`arr[0]='\0';` or  `arr[9]='\0';` would have been OK given the value passed to `foo()`.

Converting the address of the *string literal* `"attempt"` to a `char` is not good code either.  A well enabled compiler will warn of this basic coding lapse.  [@f3rmat example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54724310/2410359)

```
char *foo(char arr[]) {
  arr[10]="attempt";  <-- UB
  return arr;
}

char example[10];
example=foo(example);
```

---

The 2nd is UB because code attempted to use an uninitialized value in passing a pointer.  This "works" in that  the UB of passing an uninitialized pointer is often benign.  Since `foo()` does not use this "garbage" value and the rest of good is well defined, it "works".

```
char *foo(char* arr) {
    arr="attempt";
    return arr;
}
char *example;
example=foo(example);   // UB - likely a garbage value is passed to `foo()`.
printf("%s\n",example); // `example` is now pointing to `"attempt"`.
```

---

> I learned char array and char pointer actually using the same purpose.

Pointers and arrays are related, yet different.  Avoid the "actually using the same purpose" idea.

An *array* is like a row of houses on a street.  A *pointer* is the address of a house written on a piece of paper in your hand.  Houses ≠ scrap of paper.  You can refer to the house by its address or even a row of houses by the first house's address, yet a  house and its address are different.

Comment: My gcc version is : gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11)  And code '2' is running on my computer.

Comment: @SeptemberSKY Try compiling with more warnings likes `'-Wpedantic' '-Wall' '-Wextra' '-Wconversion'`.  "code '2' is running on my computer." does not mean code is without faults.  Code with _undefined behavior_ may _appear_ to run well.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to compile Code '1' and got the following error:

```
prog.c: In function ‘main’:
prog.c:8:12: error: assignment to expression with array type
example=foo(example);
prog.c: In function ‘foo’:
prog.c:14:12: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [- 
Wint-conversion]
arr[10]="attempt\n";
        ^
```

You get `error: assignment to expression with array type example=foo(example);` because in your left hand side, you're using an array type, which is not assignable. Assignment operator (=) needs to have a modifiable lvalue as its left operand.

You get a `warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [Wint-conversion] arr[10]="attempt\n";` because the left hand side and the right hand side in this assignment have different types.

Comment: I fixed that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Pointer and array are not the same.

```
char *arr = "attempt"
```

Here you're creating a string constant `"attempt"` and assigning its address to `arr` which is valid

```
char arr[10];
arr = "attempt";
```

This is invalid.

you can add elements to the array by following methods.

```
char arr[10] = "attempt";
char arr[10] = {'a', 't', 't', 'e', 'm', 'p', 't'};
arr[0] = 'a';
arr[1] = 't'; // and so on.
```

when you are passing the array as an argument to another function

```
arr = foo(arr);
```

you are passing the address of the zeroth element in the array `arr[0]`

Hope that helps..

Comment: `char arr[10] = "attempt";` is perfectly valid, no need to separate the `char`s one by one. However, it is not what OP has done. OP has a pointer in `foo`, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

Char arrays can be initialized but cannot be assigned.
`char example[10]="attempt";`
is valid.

But

`char example[10];`

`example="attempt"`

is not valid.

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579734/assigning-strings-to-arrays-of-characters)

Your second example works because you pass a uninitialized pointer to a function and return an address of the string literal `attempt`
which will work perfectly as mentioned in the answer by chux

Comment: "Char arrays can be initialized but cannot be assigned" is true, yet unclear here as OP's code does not attempt to assign an array anywhere.